# C# Json Parse with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json

MY JSON

```
{"Players": [{"UserId": "76561198160689142"},{"UserId": "76561198160689123"},{"UserId": "76561198160689145"},{"UserId": "76561198160689144"}]}
```

and i'm sucess on Deserialize

```
  JsonOxide obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonOxide>(jsonread);


        foreach(var item in obj.Players)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.UserId);
        }
```

class JsonOxide.cs (i'm use json2csharp to make code)

```
    public class Player
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}

public class JsonOxide
{
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

I Want Serialize my Listview Item so i try like this code but i don't know 
how to serialize

```
        List<JsonOxide> jolist = new List<JsonOxide>();
        var objs = new Object[]
        {
        //wrong code
        }
        JsonOxide jo = new JsonOxide();
```

listivew item exmaple

```
listivewitem 1.text = "test"
listviewitem 2.text = "test2"
will be save { "userid": "test"},{ "userid": "test2"}
```

and
if Listviewitem 1 is removed will edit json 
delete userid:test value  how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`SerializeObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializingjson.htm) method.

```
string players = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oxide);
```

As a full example for the structure you have provided:

```
JsonOxide oxide = new JsonOxide();
oxide.Players = new List<Player>();

oxide.Players.Add(new Player { UserId = "1" });
oxide.Players.Add(new Player { UserId = "2" });

string players = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oxide);

Console.WriteLine(players);
```

Would display:

```
{"Players":[{"UserId":"1"},{"UserId":"2"}]}
```